# ¿Como genero conjunto de letras según entrada por teclado?

Tags: java

he creado un método que genera letras aleatorias de una en una:

```
System.out.println("Introduce el número de letras que formarán las palabras aletarorias: ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//Generamos un número aleatorio:
Random rd = new Random();
        
int numConj = sc.nextInt();
        
String letras = new String("abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz");
for (int i = 0; i < numConj; i++){
     byte posLetra = (byte) rd.nextInt((letras.length()-1));
     System.out.println(letras.charAt(posLetra));
}
```

Pero necesito que en lugar de una en una sea según el número que introduzca por teclado, es decir, si introduzco el número 5 aparezcan 5 palabras inventadas con 5 letras.
Ejemplo:

```
akdje
joewg
jslgf
hnbgb
asfgg
```

No sé si es con una simple concatenación que ya he intentado... o es con otro bucle...
Cualquier ayuda es agradecida.

Comment: si, es con una concatenacion y una vez que llegas al numero ingresado mostras... eso donde esta? porque tu codigo, muestra las letras de a una...

Answer (score 2):

necesitas almacenar las palabras? Si no necesitas almacenarlas, sino simplemente imprimirlas, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
      int palabras;

        System.out.println("Introduce el número de letras que formarán las palabras aletarorias: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//Generamos un número aleatorio:
        Random rd = new Random();

        int numConj = sc.nextInt();

        String letras = new String("abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz");
        System.out.println("Introduce el número de palabras aleatorias: ");
        palabras=sc.nextInt();
        for (int j=0;j<palabras;j++){
            System.out.print("Palabra numero " + (j+1) + ":");
            for (int i = 0; i < numConj; i++){
                byte posLetra = (byte) rd.nextInt((letras.length()-1));
                System.out.print(letras.charAt(posLetra));
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Comment: Gracias!! al final ha sido una mezcla de ambas respuestas! un poquito de aquí y otro de allí...

Comment: Si, claro, es que ya depende del toque final que quieras darle tu, me alegro que te haya servido, un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

```
String letras = new String("abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz");
int tamano = letras.length();
Random random = new Random();

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{ 
   String palabra = "";

   for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
   {
      palabra += letras.charAt(random.nextInt(tamano));
   } 
   
   System.out.println(palabra);       
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es declarar la **variable letras** que contiene todas las letras del alfabeto, si lo quisieras podrías incluir cualquier caracter, la **variable tamano** guarda la longitud de esta cadena y declaramos también la **variable random** que generará los números aleatorios.

Posteriormente agregamos dos **ciclos for** que iterarán desde **1** hasta **n**, siendo **n** el número introducido por el usuario, para generar la cantidad de palabras que desee, en tu ejemplo lo explicas con el número **5**. Dentro del primer ciclo se declara la **variable palabra** que es la que irá guardando los caracteres aleatorios, cuando se entra en el segundo ciclo pues se van obteniendo los caracteres aleatorios y se guardan en la **variable palabra**, posteriormente se imprime el contenido de la **variable palabra**, y vuelve de nuevo a ejecutarse los ciclos hasta que estos lleguen a la última iteración.

Para trabajar con la **clase Random** debe hacer la siguiente importación:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

Comment: Era `java`, no `C#`. Si fuera Java está erróneo, porque `Length` con mayúscula no existe, los nombres de los `strings` van con mayúscula (`String`), es `Random` no `Ramdom`... etc. Y si es C# también está mal porque hay un montón de cosas de java, `Length()` con paréntesis no existe en c# ya que es una propiedad, ni `charAt`, ni `println` ... etc. No existe tampoco la variable `n`,

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez ya lo arreglé gracias, respecto a n, representa un número cualquiera es una generalización para que el usuario entienda el algoritmo rápido sin entrar en detalles que lo distraigan del problema a solucionar

Comment: En la línea 3 tienes el typo de `RaMdom` (pusiste una M intermedia) y en java no hay un alias para la clase `String` que se escriba con minúnscula. Corrige todos los `string` a `String`.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez gracias, así es como se hace aclarar para que uno se de cuenta de los errores que tiene y no emitir un voto negativo, que deja al que responde medio perdido sin saber el porqué, gracias

Comment: Gracias por tu disposición de mejorar tu respuesta. Tal y como está está casi perfecto. Solo te faltan corregir el paréntesis de apertura en el segundo `for` y en ese mismo `for` el espacio en el símbolo `< =`. Así quedará funcionando de maravilla, lo acabo de probar https://onlinegdb.com/poFxymxmJ.

Comment: Eran errores mínimos. Sé que tu lenguaje principal es c# y tu lógica estaba más que perfecta. Es normal confundirse con la sintaxis de un lenguaje que uno no utiliza a diario.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez hecho, gracias!!!